# PIG : How to print only certain attributes from Grouped Bag

Tags: apache-pig

I  have a grouped result which looks exactly like below :

```
| grouped     | group:chararray    | log:bag{:tuple(driverId:chararray,truckId:chararray,eventTime:chararray,eventType:chararray,longitude:chararray,latitude:chararray,eventKey:chararray,CorrelationId:chararray,driverName:chararray,routeId:chararray,routeName:chararray,eventDate:chararray)}
```

When I perform below :

```
x = FOREACH grouped GENERATE {log.driverId, log.truckId, log.driverName};
illustrate x;
```

The out put am getting is :

```
| x     | :bag{:tuple(:bag{:tuple(driverId:chararray)})}                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       | {({(11), (11)}), ({(74), (39)}), ({(Jamie Engesser), (Jamie Engesser)})} |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where as my expectation is :

```
{({(11, 74, Jamie Engesser), (11,39,Jamie Engesser)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits @LostInOverflow, good work! I expect that will be approved shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solutions

Since

Group was a tuple and The adjacent result was Bag i had to use Nested FOREACH like below :

```
x = FOREACH grouped{
        val1 = group;
        vals = FOREACH log GENERATE driverId, truckId, driverName;
        GENERATE val1, vals;
        };
```

So this selected only the required attributes from the given result.

Please comment if some one knows a better/optimal/easier way of doing it.

Thanks